# How to make an xorg.conf file

Tags: nvidia, ati, xorg

I just installed Ubuntu 12.10 and I need to make a custom `xorg.conf` file. By default, there is not an `xorg.conf` file on my system. I know what I need to write in the config, but I just don't know how to make X load it...

Should I put my custom commands in a file that already exists? Where is it?
Should I make my own `xorg.conf` file and put it in `/etc/X11`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For Nvidia based cards I suggest to install the binary driver from the repositories and then run `nvidia-xconfig`. It will create a fishbone with basic configuration. Similar commands for other binary drivers may exist.

If there isn't, just start by creating the file and enter your settings.

All configuration not set will X find by itself. It has a lot of heuristic, but yes, it may be hard to find the right setting keywords and values in order to tweak everything to your needs.

Comment: I installed the driver but it didn't make the x file. But I resolved my issue anyways.

Answer (score 23):

If you would want full and proper `xorg.conf` file (tested on Ubuntu 12.10):

1. Switch to console mode: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
2. Kill x server:

   ```
   sudo service lightdm stop
   ```
3. Generate new xorg.conf file:

   ```
   sudo X -configure
   ```

   This will create `xorg.conf.new` file in your current directory.
4. Rename and move:

   ```
   sudo mv xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf
   ```
5. Return to GUI:

   ```
   sudo start lightdm
   ```

taken from [Linux Mint forums](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/877) (go to point `3. In Mint, xorg.conf is not present by default...`)

Comment: Running Gnome 3.12, I replaced `lightdm` with `gdm` and it was generated. Thank you!

Comment: This solution saved me after hours of trying on my own.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Worked. for kubuntu its `sddm`

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. It's as simple as making a file called "xorg.conf" and putting it in "/etc/X11/". I guess I thought that seemed too simple :P

X will read the config file and try to accept your statements. It will then auto config anything you don't explicitly say.

Comment: For use with the nvidia driver, and `nvidia-setup`, creating an empty file `xorg.conf`, in `/etc/X11/` or somewhere else where I have write access, did not help for me. (Error: "could not parse...")