# How to change the color depth in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04

please help me changing the color depth in Ubuntu 12.04!

(Any idea why it is not part of "System Setting" in GUI?)

I need 16bpp to get xrdp running in Ubuntu on virtualBox.

Instruchtions basesd on TTY and 
`sudo service xdm stop` or `sudo service gdm stop` 
result in `unrecognised service`.

Answer (score 1):

A quick way would be to change the screen section in xorg.conf

> /etc/X11/xorg.conf

In the screen section you will find Depth and/or DefaultDepth, make these 24 and you will have 16bpp colors upon restart.

If you do not have a xorg.conf yet, you can find [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217758/how-to-make-an-xorg-conf-file) how to make one.

Comment: Hi Requist! <br>

Comment: Sounds pretty quick, but this file is not existing by default in Ubuntu 12.04. Please show me the text to place into xorg.conf.

Comment: The text differs, but I added a link in my answer on how to make a xorg.conf.