# output of sudo nvidia-xconfig is different

Tags: nvidia

When I run `sudo nvidia-xconfig`, I get this output.

```
Using X configuration file: "/etc/X11/XF86Config".
Backed up file '/etc/X11/XF86Config' as '/etc/X11/XF86Config.backup'
New X configuration file written to '/etc/X11/XF86Config'
```

Normally the configuration file will be written to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. Why is my case different?

Answer (score 0):

> XFree86 uses a configuration file called XF86Config for its initial setup. This configuration file is searched for in the following places when the server is started as a normal user:

```
...
/etc/X11/$XF86CONFIG
/usr/X11R6/etc/X11/$XF86CONFIG
/etc/X11/XF86Config-4
/etc/X11/XF86Config
...
```

[Source](http://www.xfree86.org/4.0/XF86Config.5.html)

Comment: can u explain in more details??

Comment: @SamTew it's just another way for it to store the configuration.

Comment: So it is doesn't matter whether is /etc/X11/XF86Config or /etc/X11/xorg.conf? It still working the same?

Comment: @SamTew I think they do different things, but should work. You may like this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/281685/186134