# How do I remove the Nvidia logo on boot without using a xorg.conf?

Tags: nvidia, xorg

I would like to remove the Nvidia bootsplash logo, however solutions on the internet recommend adding `Option "NoLogo"` in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.

However my machine doesn't have that config file and since I plug into different monitors all the time (it's my travelling computer) I would like to avoid having a xorg.conf at all and let the magical autoconfiguring thing just happen.

Is there a way I can remove the logo without a xorg.conf?

Comment: You don't need to have monitor-specific settings in `xorg.conf`, so why would magical autoconfiguring be affected?

Comment: Odd... I don't recall having disabled the logo, but I don't see it when X starts up anymore. I'm using 352.41 on Arch. Which version of the drivers do you have?

Comment: Adjusting autoconfigured only as much as needed is definitely better than disabling autoconfiguration altogether. Especially that in my case, xorg.conf made with `X -configure` as in http://askubuntu.com/a/281685/23373 yielded configuration that did not work. @JoergeCastro's own answer did the trick.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Should work if you run

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig --no-logo
```

That will write a minimal xorg.conf file, which should be fine.

I am not sure there is a way to do this outside of xorg.conf

Answer (score 10):

Ok found a nice way to do this:

Make a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/nosplash.conf` with this:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Nvidia Card"
    Driver "nvidia"
    VendorName "NVIDIA Corporation"
    Option "NoLogo" "true"
EndSection
```

That way I don't need a minimal xorg.conf at all in `/etc/X11`.

Source: http://steamcommunity.com/groups/steamuniverse/discussions/1/496880203075108061/

Comment: This doesn't appear to even be used, according to my `Xorg.0.log`

Comment: Seems to work, thanks. Created a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file though. `Xorg.0.log` gives `[     9.967] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "NoLogo" "true"`