# How to enable GPU mining on a spare card not used for main display?

Tags: graphics, ati, radeon, gpu, bitcoin

I am using an internal (Intel) video card for my main display. This is selected as per BIOS settings.

I'd like to see how the GPU mining is on a AMD card I put into my PC.
It's a "Cape Verde PRO [Radeon HD 7750/8740 / R7 250E]", by the way.
I tried to follow some tutorials but, in the end, I just messed with the X settings.
Is there a way to install and load the needed kernel modules and libraries without touching the X settings?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to install proprietary drivers without risking changes to xorg.conf . Trying to use your integrated graphics will only complicate things further. You may want to try a headless linux / server edition and just forget about the integrated graphics if mining is really your main goal. Unity is known to take its toll on light weight gpus, if you want a desktop you might try Lubuntu then driver install, or start with server linux, install gfx driver, then install a desktop.

Making a backup of xorg.conf before this is done can save a little trouble in some cases. Check out section 4.2 in this link below for a step by step.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD

Edit- even though your computer did not need a xorg.conf on basic install, you often need to add one to gain more control over gpus.

These examples are using an Nvidia gpu to generate a xorg.conf, however I see nothing that would stop it from working with AMD/ATI (except for the one answer that calls for nvidia-xconfig)

Instead "sudo amdconfig --adapter=all --initial" can be used as a replacement for that command to generate a xorg.conf for multiple gpus.

[How to make an xorg.conf file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217758/how-to-make-an-xorg-conf-file)

Full documentation can be found here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config

This includes some docs on dual gpu systems with hybrid graphics like yours.

There are no cryptocurrencies left that will generate anything but a loss in electrical usage when mined with a gpu though due to asics being the large part of the scene, if it is merely for testing and curiosity of how it works by all means plug away, you may want to visit the bitcoin.stackexchange for some further advice.

Comment: My default setup has no xorg.conf at all. I am not going to rely on GPUs for mining. I am just wishing to test how it works with different cards. And I only can have one (apart of the one builtin the CPU).

Comment: It doesn't help to back up the X11 configuration files: the system gets completely screwed up and rendered unable to boot to X. Any other info?