# CRT coil whine?

Tags: 17.04

When I use Ubuntu 17.04, 16.04, or Linux Mint 18.1, I hear coil whine coming from my CRT. When I use Windows 7, or Linux Mint 17.3 using fglrx drivers, I get no coil whine (Windows I use solely for gaming, Mint 17.3 is acting up). While it may seem that the coil whine goes away with fglrx because it's suited for older hardware, on Windows 7 I use the latest ReLive drivers, and have no coil whine. I use dual monitors.

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

The resolution and refresh rate will affect coil whine (specifically, the horizontal refresh rate, which is the refresh rate multiplied by the vertical resolution plus a vertical blanking interval).  It's likely that you are using a different refresh rate or resolution on Ubuntu as you do with Windows or Ubuntu with fglrx drivers.

Comment: Is there any way to use resolutions not displayed in xrandr? There are some available on Windows 7 that don't show up in xrandr.

Comment: @Mr.Wolf Try creating a xorg.conf file to get more resolutions from your monitors.  See:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/217758/how-to-make-an-xorg-conf-file